# MVC application redirecting to Microsoft Login page(For Azure AD) instead of custom designed log in page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

My `MVC` application is meant to load up the Login page I developed first, from which a button is to be clicked and only then redirected to the Microsoft login page for `Azure AD` authentication. On my local it works, but not when published to Azure(App Service), I have changed the redirect URL to use the `xxxx.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login` in Azure AD but its STILL redirecting to the Microsoft Login page first.

### EDIT

I came to realize that the Redirect URL that I changed would only effect after authentication.So if the user authenticates successfully, it would redirect to that url.

## What I have done

What I did was create the app service, publish my MVC app to it, then went to AAD and registered the app there. When I run the azurewebsites URL, it goes straight to the MS login page, however as mentioned, in my local it goes straight to the login page as it should. The redirect URL that I changed was in AAD. I did not do any other changes in the app service.Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Has anyone experienced this before ?

Comment: Seems like your app responds with a 401 on receiving an anonymous user request when deployed to Azure but not when deployed to your local machine. Is that right? Could it be that you have configured AAD authentication on the Azure App Service itself? If so, App Service will trap incomming requests and redirect to AAD. Are you going to the same page in first request to the app whether you run it locally or in Azure?

Comment: Marc is correct in that you can't configure AAD auth at app service level if you want this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. This is all still new to me, so forgive me if I misunderstand anything you bring to my attention. I was not aware you could configure AAD in the App Service ? What I did was create the app service, publish my MVC app to it, then went to AAD and registered the app there. When I run the azurewebsites URL, it goes straight to the MS login page, however as mentioned, in my local it goes straight to the login page as it should. The redirect URL that I changed was in AAD. I did not do any other changes in the app service.Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Comment: Anyone got any ideas ? I am still struggling with this :(

Answer (score 0):

So I seem to have found the problem:

1. My routing was set to Home/Index in my `RouteConfig.cs` and I assumed because I set my Account/Login as the start page, that it would go to that page(Like it does on my local), but this is not the case, I needed to change my route to Account/Login for it to hit my 
   landing page.

   ```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
       routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
       routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
       {
           controller = "Account",
           action = "Login",
           id = UrlParameter.Optional
       }).RouteHandler = new DashRouteHandler();
   }
   ```
2. I needed to remove the [Authorize] attribute from my Account/Login

This made it hit my landing page first and I have a signin function that redirects to the MS Login Page for Azure AD login.